# How to conceal narrator's gender? — Comment garder secret le genre du narrateur ?

Tags: genre, genre-biologique, style-de-rédaction

Occasionally in English texts I have strayed across stories in which for whatever reason the author does not wish the gender of the narrator to be immediately apparent. In English giving away the narrator's gender is easily avoided through the use of ambiguous or vague self-description.

But in French, a phrase like “*je me suis levée*” immediately gives away that the narrator is female.

How is this avoided? Or is it impossible in French?

---

Je suis parfois tombé sur des histoires en langue anglaise dans lesquelles l'auteur ne souhaitait pas que le genre du narrateur soit connu dès le début. En anglais c'est facile de ne pas vendre la mèche, il suffit de ne faire que des descriptions vagues ou ambiguës de soi.

Mais en français, un simple « *je me suis levée* » vous trahirait.

Comment s'en sortir ? Peut-être est-ce impossible de garder le genre secret en français ?

Comment: Ça me rappelle Perec qui cite Proust dans _La disparition_: "Durant un grand laps, on m'alita tôt."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's true that it would be a grammatical mistake to write “*Je me suis levé*” when the narrator is a woman, just to keep the gender secret; even if we don't know the gender yet, you have to write “*levée*”.

To avoid such phrases where the gender is revealed might be a little bit more difficult in French than in English, but it is not so difficult with a little bit of imagination.
“*Je me suis levée tôt ce matin…*” could be replaced by “*Ayant quitté mon lit tôt ce matin…*”.
You will have to avoid phrases with “*je suis partie* (ou *restée*, etc.)” by using passive sentences or others detours.

Note that if you really want to play with the gender of the narrator, using (some) job titles as neutral is possible.

> « Bonjour Docteur ! »
>
> Le juge est arrivé.
>
> Le médecin a dit que...
>
> Le professeur pense que ...

In these examples, the doctor, judge, doctor (again) or professor could be either a man or a woman (same as English). Even if “*le juge*” is a woman, you don't write “*Le juge est arrivée*”. But you might write “*La juge est arrivée*”. Still, using male form as neutral is possible (and feminist people might consider it more correct).

Answer (score 8):

Il est tout à fait possible de dé-corréler le genre et la personne en utilisant son activité vitale, les temps simples (imparfait, présent, futur) et le dialogue, sans oublier les prénoms aussi bien féminins que masculins:

> Après avoir réglé les derniers détails du dossier X.. contre Y.. je
>   décidais de m'octroyer une fin de journée distrayante.
> Demain je
>   serai la partie adverse d'un confrère ou d'une consœur ... un jeu de miroir.
>
> Allo Camille? .. c'est Claude à l'appareil, je peux passer te prendre
>   tout à l'heure ...

Comment: M'est avis que tu aimes un peu trop les "s". "Je décidai" et "Demain je serai" semblent plus corrects, non?

Comment: @Djaian d'accord pour le futur, mais est-ce que l'imparfait est vraiment coupable ici ?

Comment: Le passé simple semble plus correct. La prise de décision elle-même étant en principe quelque chose de bref. En principe l'imparfait indique une action qui s'étale sur la durée.

Comment: @Djaian Intuitivement j'opte pour l'imparfait, pour une situation  où la personne a hésité avant de s'octroyer de courtes vacances et non une impulsion due à une saturation de travail.

Comment: Tu dirais plutôt: "je pris la décision de m'octroyer une fin de journée distrayante" ou "je prenais la décision de m'octroyer une fin de journée distrayante" ?
Techniquement parlant, les deux sont possibles. Toutefois, le passé simple semble plus naturel.

Comment: @Djaian Problème de contexte : dans un rapport, un constat, quelque chose d'administratif, de convenu, *je pris* ; dans un dialogue, un récit, *je prenais*, pour insister sur la difficulté du choix, le coté inhabituel d'arrêter son travail au cours d'une journée.

Comment: ouais, c'est pas faux. :-)